# Closing/cleaning up "mixed" file descriptors / sockets

Tags: c, sockets, io, file-descriptor

When I create a socket using accept() and make a FILE out of it using fdopen(), what do I have to do to clean everything up? Do I need to do fclose() on the FILE, shutdown() and close() on the socket, or only the shutdown() and or close() or fclose()? If I don't do fclose(), do I have to free() the FILE pointer manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From man fdopen:

> The file descriptor is not dup’ed, and will be closed when the stream  created  by  fdopen()  is closed

So I would just use fclose(), which also closes the underlying file descriptor. I don't know whether shutdown() is needed, either.

Answer (score 3):

From http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fclose.html

> The fclose() function will perform a
>   close() on the file descriptor that is
>   associated with the stream pointed to
>   by stream.

If you've wrapped your socket in a stream it probably no longer makes sense to shutdown(), at least not without flushing the stream first. But I won't swear to that, because I don't know that there are no uses where you'd want to shutdown() rather than just close().

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 things here you need to clean up: the stream represented by `FILE` and the file descriptor represented by the socket. You need to close the stream first, then the file descriptor. So, in general you will need to `fclose()` any `FILE` objects, then `close()` any file descriptors.

Personally I have never used `shutdown()` when I want to cleanup after myself, so I can't say.

### edit

Others have correctly pointed out that `fdclose()` will also close the underlying file descriptor, and since calling `close()` on a close file descriptor will lead to an error, in this case you only need `fdclose()`.