# Properly close a file with both a file descriptor and file pointer

Tags: c, posix

For formatted writes with `fprintf()`, I'm using a `FILE` pointer obtained from a file descriptor created by `mkstemp()` ([see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941464/how-to-get-a-file-pointer-from-a-file-descriptor)):

```
fd = mkstemp(tmpName);

FILE *fp = fdopen(fd, "w");
fprintf(fp, "#EXTM3U\n");
```

What is the proper procedure to close the file?

```
fclose(fp) // only?

fclose(fp); // both?
close(fd);

close(fd); // only?
```

Comment: C or C++: Pick one, they are not the same language.

Comment: Essentially  the same question as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108043/closing-cleaning-up-mixed-file-descriptors-sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html):

> The **fdopen()** function associates a stream with the existing file
>          descriptor, *fd*.
>
> [...]
>
> The
>          file descriptor is not dup'ed, and will be closed when the stream
>          created by **fdopen()** is closed.

Please also note:

> The *mode* of the stream (one of the values "r", "r+",
>          "w", "w+", "a", "a+") must be compatible with the mode of the file
>          descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

The man page for `fdopen` specifies the following:

> The file descriptor is not dup'ed, and will be closed when the stream created by fdopen() is closed.

The man page for `fclose` supports this:

> The fclose() function shall perform the equivalent of a close() on the file descriptor that is associated with the stream pointed to by stream

So, `fclose` is enough...

Comment: How does this relate to the information given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13691168/1187415  and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fclose.html ? *"The fclose() function shall perform the equivalent of a close() on the file descriptor that is associated with the stream pointed to by stream"*

Comment: @MartinR, you are right! I stand corrected.